# PHP nested category and subcategory JSON

Tags: php, json

I want to get nested JSON with category and sub category for my app, and this is my code

```
// get all items from myorder table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT co.country, cl.city_code, cl.city_name
                       FROM country as co, city_list as cl
                       WHERE co.id_country = cl.id_country") or die(mysql_error());

$response["location"] = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $categories['Cities'][] = array(
            'code'         => $row['city_code'],
            'city'         => $row['city_name'],
    );
}

foreach ($categories as $key => $value) {
    $category_data[] = array(
        'category'      => $key,
        'category_list' => $value,
    );
}

array_push($response["location"], $categories);
// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
```

and this is the result:

```
 {
location: [
    {
        USA: {
            Country: "USA"
            Cities: [
                {
                    code: "AL",
                    city: "ALABAMA"
                },
                {
                    code: "AR",
                    city: "Arkansas"
                },
                {
                    code: "DC",
                    city: "Distric of Columbia"
                },
                {
                    code: "LA",
                    city: "Louisiana"
                }
                ]
            }
        }

    ]
}
```

I want to get this format:

```
{
location: [
    Country: "USA"
    Cities: [
        {
            code: "AL",
            city: "ALABAMA"
        },
        {
            code: "AR",
            city: "Arkansas"
        },
        {
            code: "DC",
            city: "Distric of Columbia"
        },
        {
            code: "LA",
            city: "Louisiana"
        },


    ]
}
```

how can I achieve this? is there any reference that I can look into?
any help?

Comment: Is this dynamic `Country: "USA"`?

Comment: `co.country` is the name of the country in your request ?

Comment: yup, Country object will list several country...

yup, co.country will call country name in the process...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, order by the country name in your request.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if (! isset($categories[$row['country']])) {
          $categories[$row['country']] = array('Country' => $row['country']);
          $categories[$row['country']]['Cities'] = array();
    }

    $categories[$row['country']]['Cities'][] = array(
        'code'         => $row['city_code'],
        'city'         => $row['city_name'],
    );

}

... rest of your code
```

By the way, you should stop using mysql_* functions and use mysqli_*. As written in every post on SO ..

Comment: please see the result in my updated post, I got that result with your code...I will change mysql with mysqli after this ;)